# How to make parent element to be the size of the child element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have iframe inside div element:

```
<div id="toolbarArea" class="toolbarArea"  data-Date="11/2016"> 
            <img id="toolbarTitle" width="15px" height="15px" src="../stdicons/derem/threePoints.png">
            <iframe id="frTools" style="width:94%%;height:90%%;top:0px; position: absolute;" name="tbFrame" src="/container/serol/chegsorc.aspx?LOCALE=en" frameBorder="0"></iframe>             
          </div>

.toolbarArea{   
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:450px; 
    position:relative; 
    z-index:100;
    height:30px;

    border: solid 1px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

I get scroll on the div,
how to make parent element to be the size of the child element to prevent the sccroll appereance.

Answer (score 0):

Removing  the  `width` and `height` from the class `toolbarArea` should do the trick :

```
.toolbarArea {   
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 100;
  border: solid 1px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the scroll appearance with this:

```
width: auto;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of `float: left/right` or `display: inline/inline-block` for parent to be same width as it's content

```css
#toolbarArea {
  background-color: #aaa;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#toolbarTitle {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

#frTools {
  width:94%;
  height:90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbarArea" class="toolbarArea" data-Date="11/2016">
  <img id="toolbarTitle" src="../stdicons/derem/threePoints.png">
  <iframe id="frTools" name="tbFrame" src="/container/serol/chegsorc.aspx?LOCALE=en"></iframe>
</div>
```

---

Please note that your iFrame css is not valid, as `94%%` must be `94%` and so on.

Comment: thanks for post.the div is invisible when I use classes above.I only see three points"..."